# Using Trusted Connection for Connection String - MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework-4

I am trying to simply use my local sql server database for a test application but none of the connection strings i've tried are working.

I was able to prove local access by doing this:

```
C:\Users\myusername>sqlcmd -S MYNAME-MBP-W7\SQLEXPRESS
1> Go
1> select name from sys.databases
2> Go

name
------------------
master

tempdb

model

msdb

(4 rows affected)
1>
```

So then, I tried to set up a local connection to this locally running database server in my VS project, in the web.config file using trusted connection authentication, just like the command [found here](http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server-2008) under Trusted Connection This page shows something like:

```
Data Source=myServerAddress;
Initial Catalog=myDataBase;
Integrated Security=SSPI;
User ID=myDomain\myUsername;Password=myPassword;
```

I tried this but get "server not found" errors

```
<add name="GuitarContext" 
            providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" 
            connectionString="Data Source=(localhost);
            Initial Catalog=aspnet-GuitarCollector-20130830123055;
            Integrated Security=SSPI; 
            user id =PDC1\myusername; password=mypassword" />
```

Any help troubleshooting and/or solving this is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have at least two problems.

First, You can't use a username and password with trusted connection.  The whole point is that it uses your worker processes configured identity to access the database, or whatever identity you are impersonating.

Second, your "test" is using the SQLEXPRESS instance, while your connection string is using the default instance (no instance specified).  You need to specify the instance if that's what you're using.